# How to Interrupt an IO block?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, signals

I'm working on an assignment multi threaded server client model. It's in C , Since it's an ongoing assignment, I can't share code. 
Here is my problem,

I have dynamically created threads for each client, When I get `CTRL+C` on the server I need to properly cleanup the resources, In the main thread & Other client handling threads I check a `KILL` variable within an infinite block, If I receive a signal, I set the `KILL` to 1.

But, When the `TCP` is waiting for `accept()` it can't go loop  unless it receives a client connection. Consider a situation like this. I run the server, No clients are connected. I hit `CTRL+C` , `KILL` is set to 1. But `main()` can't check the `KILL` until `accept()` receive something. I tried to use `select()` and give a timeout, But It freezes the entire machine within a minute.

```
activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , &time_val);
```

Can anyone suggest me a better way of doing it ? I mean other than polling?

-Regards

Comment: Just fix the bug in your `select` code so it doesn't freeze the machine. Most likely, you're incorrectly reusing the read fd_set. Whatever, you do, *do not* follow Ron Struempf's advice and call `close` while the socket is in use by another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could block on accept() in a background thread, and when you want to kill the process, close the socket and the accept() call will terminate.

Comment: you mean do I have to have separate thread for that purpose and block the accept upon KILL is set ?

Comment: Since I can't see your code, I don't know what your exact situation is, but a call to accept() blocks until a connection is made or the socket is closed.  You said your main thread is blocked on accept(), so either another thread needs to close the socket, or you need to move the accept() call to a secondary thread.

Comment: Got it. Great man. I think it will solve the issue. Kudos..! :)

Comment: **NO**, **NO**, **NO**. This does not work and you *must* not do this. You cannot release a resource while another thread is, or might be, using it. You must never `close` a socket in one thread while another thread is blocked on that socket. It is *impossible* to make this work reliably.

Comment: Consider this case: The thread that calls `accept` gets descheduled right before it manages to call `accept`. By sheer bad luck, the following happens: One thread calls `close` to terminate the process. Another thread calls `socket` to get a new socket, which gets the same file descriptor as the one that was `closed`. Now, the thread that was about to call `accept` gets scheduled, and it calls `accept` on the **wrong** endpoint. Now the thread that opens the new socket calls `accept` itself. Boom, connections can be accepted by code expecting to be using another endpoint entirely.

Comment: You say NO, NO, NO, but offer no answers.  If you have an app with many threads, potentially all opening and closing sockets, then what you describe may be a low odds race condition, but if you open a single socket, use it, and close it when you are ready to exit, and have no other threads in your app opening other sockets, no such race condition would exist.

Comment: Do you know of another way to cause a thread blocked on accept() to exit?